# Book recommendation on complex analysis with historical motivation

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation

I am looking for a "thick" book on complex analysis, which also has historical details such as the motivation behind it. Which problem lead to the creation/discovery of a certain topic. E.g. what is the reason behind fundamental groups how is it in connection with topology. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remmert’s *Theory of Complex Functions* may be helpful in this regard.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One book that fits your description quite well is
[Classical Analysis in the Complex Plane](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1071619632)
by Robert B. Burckel (1152 pages, with plenty of historical comments).

Comment: thank you so much, will definetly have a look on it. For me personally it helps tremendously to have those information do not know why. It enables me to visualize it better.